# Pronunciation of "rather"

Tags: pronunciation

In [this YouTube video](https://youtu.be/Ohrh34AaG2M) around 7:02 the author says:

> [...] *rather* is one of those words which can have a different meaning [...] depending on how you pronounce it.

This got me interested and I found two pronunciations in a couple of Internet dictionaries (for example [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rather) and [Wikitionary](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/rather)): with an emphasis on the first syllable or on the last. 
However I think I have never heard it being pronounced the second way.

How does the pronunciation change the meaning of this word and what are some examples of sentences with "rather" being pronounced by emphasizing the second syllable?

Comment: Nobody pronounces *rather* with an accent on the last syllable.

Comment: @PeterShor it can be. "Do you want to go out?" — "Rath***er***".

Comment: @WeatherVane: I don't think that's an accent on the last syllable. That's secondary stress on the second syllable. But I do see what you mean.

Comment: @KubaSzymanowski can you please cite those internet dictionaries? Also the video is 13 minutes long, and appears to be about the word "really". Can you give a time of the relevant part?

Comment: @WeatherVane I added the video timestamp and dictionary links to my question.

Comment: Thank you. The M-W pronunciation alternative is as I commented earlier: *interjectionally*. Besides that, I pronounce all the usages in M-W the same way.

Comment: [Here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/rather) is a example pronunciation of *rather* with the accent on the second syllable. Scroll down until you get to the *exclamation* definition. It still has a lot of stress on the first syllable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The meaning of *rather* with stress on the second syllable is *certainly*. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/rather) defines it as

> *dated British:*
>   Used to express emphatic affirmation, agreement, or acceptance.

[Cambridge Dictionaries](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/rather) has an example pronunciation of *rather* with the primary accent on the second syllable. Scroll down until you get to the *exclamation* definition. It still has a lot of stress on the first syllable.